# count lines in a compressed file

Tags: command-line, unix

if i have a .gz file on unix which has certain number of lines.
How could i count the lines on unix without uncompressing it.

Comment: Without extracting the archive you can't count the lines.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846062/wc-gzipped-files

Answer (score 83):

You can obviously not count newlines if the file is still compressed.

But you can decompress to a stream, and count the newlines in that stream, without ever writing the (decompressed) file to disk. That would go something like so:

```
zcat file.gz | wc -l
```

zcat for decompress & cat, wc for wordcount. See man pages for both if you want to know more.

**EDIT**

If you do not have zcat, zcat is just another name for `gunzip -c`.

Comment: On Unices where `gzip` is distinct from `compress`, you want `gzcat`.

Answer (score 13):

This also seems to work - grep for the number of line-endings in the file

```
zgrep -Ec "$" file.gz
```

Comment: This gives a different (much higher) answer for me than piping to `wc -l`

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it quickly, I recommend using 'pigz' (which IIRC stands for "Parallel Implementation of GZip"). I just had a similar situation where I wanted to count the number of lines in a bunch of gzip'ed files and here was my solution:

```
for x in *.gz; do unpigz -p 8 -c $x | wc -l && echo $x; done
```

Which gave me the number of lines and the file it counted from on alternating lines, using 8 processors. It ran quickly!

Comment: Or if unpigz is not available, simply with `for x in *.fastq.gz; do zcat "$x" | wc -l && echo $x; done`

Comment: thanks Peter, 
from your command, I made a zzcat alternative to zcat
alias zzcat='unpigz -p 8 -c'
even on a single core pigz is already faster, more than 4 cores do not really help in my case due to IO bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

Use this command:

```
gzgrep -c $ filename.gz
```

The command `gzgrep` behaves the same as `grep` but on gzip compressed files. It decompress the file on the fly for the regex matching.

In this case `-c` instruct the command to output number of matched lines and the regex `$` matches end of line so it matches every line or the file.

The final result is identical to `gzip -dc filename.gz | grep -c $`.

Comment: Is `gzgrep` available on other systems than Solaris?

Comment: No. On other systems, command would be
zgrep -c $ filename.gz

Comment: Although one might intuitively think this is better than zcat+wc, when I time them, they take the same amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with a rough estimate rather than an exact count, and actually extracting the whole file or zgrepping it for line endings would both take much too long (which was my situation just now), you can:

```
zcat "$file" | head -1000 > 1000-line-sample.txt
ls -ls 1000-line-sample.txt "$file"
```

then the approximate line count is `1000 * (size of $file) / (size of 1000-line-sample)`, as long as your data is fairly homogeneous per line.

Comment: Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @AlexMoore-Niemi It's using the first 1000 lines to estimate the compression ratio.

Answer (score 1):

`gzip -cd <file.gz> | wc -l`

This worked for me.

Comment: Does not work on ubuntu 20 / 22.